# Digital envelope routines::unsupported

Tags: javascript, reactjs

This is the error which is being received:

```
Error: error:0308010C:digital envelope routines::unsupported
    at new Hash (node:internal/crypto/hash:71:19)
    at Object.createHash (node:crypto:133:10)
    at module.exports (/home/haya/Downloads/FWZ copied/node_modules/webpack/lib/util/createHash.js:135:53)
    at NormalModule._initBuildHash (/home/haya/Downloads/FWZ copied/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:417:16)
    at /home/haya/Downloads/FWZ copied/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:452:10
    at /home/haya/Downloads/FWZ copied/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:323:13
    at /home/haya/Downloads/FWZ copied/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:367:11
    at /home/haya/Downloads/FWZ copied/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:233:18
    at context.callback (/home/haya/Downloads/FWZ copied/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:111:13)
    at /home/haya/Downloads/FWZ copied/node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js:59:103 {
  opensslErrorStack: [ 'error:03000086:digital envelope routines::initialization error' ],
  library: 'digital envelope routines',
  reason: 'unsupported',
  code: 'ERR_OSSL_EVP_UNSUPPORTED'
}
```

> Check whether your Node.js and React.js versions if they are
> compatible or not

The project doesn't run on

```
npm start
```

but does run after the commands:

```
export NODE_OPTIONS=--openssl-legacy-provider 
npm start
```

Want this to run only on

```
npm start
```

To do this you just gotta change a tiny thing in your package.json:
From this:

```
"start": "react-scripts start",
```

To this:

```
"start": "react-scripts --openssl-legacy-provider start",
```

Comment: Did you tried npm audit fix --force?

Comment: I've got my answer already but, Thnx <3